# Android Screenlock/Keyguard after Startup without SIM card

Tags: android, autorun, keyguard

I am developing for the HTC Desire HD Android 2.3.3 API10.
I have an app registered as homescreen which now finally starts up nicely after booting.
Problem is, there is a Keyguard right after booting up, which is telling me there is no SIM card inserted, emergency only ... which I have to manually unlock.

The device will be part of an installation hanging from the ceiling or something, so it must start without human interaction.

How can I circumvent the startup keyguard?

I have this in the manifest:
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD" />`

and this code in place before the app does anything else:

```
Window wind = this.getWindow(); //Is this preventing Keyguard on startup??
wind.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED);
wind.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);
```

Comment: i solved it by inserting this obvious code   `wind.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD);`

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by inserting this code:

```
wind.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD);
```